# Why is the slider not updating the label when I make the slider programmatically?

Tags: swift, uilabel, uislider

I made a slider and label **PROGRAMMATICALLY**. I wanted the label to display the value of the slider, but the label only displays the value I initially assigned.

Code:

```
var num: CGFloat = 9

override func viewDidLoad() {
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 40))
    label.text = "\(num)"
    self.view.addSubview(label)

    let slider = UISlider(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30)) 
    slider.value = Float(num)
    slider.addTarget(self, action: "changedSliderValue:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
    self.view.addSubview(slider)
}

func changedSliderValue(sender: UISlider!){
    num = CGFloat(sender.value)
    label.text = "\(num)"
}
```

When I did `print(label.text!)`, it showed me that `label.text` was changing as I changed the slider value. But then, why doesn't the label change on my view controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create `IBAction` for that with slider as shown in below code:

```
@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {

    num = sender.value
    label.text = "\(num)"
}
```

For more Info refer [THIS](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/uislider-tutorial-ios8-swift) tutorial.

**Update:**

Below is your complete working code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var num: CGFloat = 9
    let label = UILabel(frame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 40))

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        label.text = "\(num)"
        self.view.addSubview(label)

        let slider = UISlider(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 60, 30))
        slider.value = Float(num)
        slider.addTarget(self, action: "changedSliderValue:", forControlEvents: .ValueChanged)
        self.view.addSubview(slider)
    }

    func changedSliderValue(sender: UISlider!){
        num = CGFloat(sender.value)
        label.text = "\(num)"
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, if I didn't make it clear, but I created the slider and label **programmatically**

Comment: than set target to slider programatically @Amanda like `slider.addTarget(self, action: "sliderValueChanged:", forControlEvents:.ValueChanged)` ...more info ...check http://www.apptuitions.com/programmatically-creating-uiview-uislider-uiswitch-using-swift/

Comment: happy to help you..:)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have bind action to slider....
Here num is CGFloat value and sender.value is Float...

```
var num: CGFloat = 9
label.text = "\(num)"

@IBAction func sliderValueChanged(sender: UISlider) {
    num = CGFloat(sender.value)
    label.text = "\(num)"
 }
```